# Как следует перевести "tag wiki"?

Tags: поддержка, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

По поводу tag wiki ([So what's this "tag wiki" thing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57992/so-whats-this-tag-wiki-thing), спасибо @Yura Ivanov за наводку), которое есть отдельная вики-страница с описанием метки: как будем переводить связанные термины?

- Tag wiki?
- Tag wiki post?
- Non tag wiki post?
- Tag wiki edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Выбранный вариант*.

- tag wiki = описание метки
- tag wiki post = редактура описания метки
- non tag wiki post = сообщение вне описаний меток
- tag wiki edit = редактирование описания метки

---

*Остальные варианты*.

- Вариант 1.

  - tag wiki = вики для меток/для метки
  - tag wiki post = работа в вики для меток
  - non tag wiki post = сообщение не в вики для меток
  - tag wiki edit = редактирование вики для меток